# В Intellij Idea код Process finished with exit code 1

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Выдаёт в Intellij Idea код Process finished with exit code 1, при этом не выдаёт реузльтат. У кого то было такое?

```
package com.ticTacToe;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Game game = new Game();
        game.eraseField();
        game.showField();
        System.out.print("[" + "]");
    }
}

package com.ticTacToe;

public class Game {

    private static final int FIELD_SIZE = 3;
    private static final char FIELD_CLEAR = ' ';
    private final char[][] field = new char[FIELD_SIZE][FIELD_SIZE];

    public void eraseField() {
        for (int i = 0; i <= FIELD_SIZE; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j <= FIELD_SIZE; i++) {
                field[i][j] = FIELD_CLEAR;
            }
        }
    }

    public void showField() {
        for (int i = 0; i <= FIELD_SIZE; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j <= FIELD_SIZE; i++) {
                System.out.print("[" + field[i][j] + "]");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`exit code > 0` свидетельствует об ошибке в процессе выполнения.

Что, в общем-то, и неудивительно, ведь ваш код должен генерировать `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. А для исправления этого, во всех четырёх циклах условие

```
<= FIELD_SIZE
```

замените на

```
< FIELD_SIZE
```

P.S. И ознакомьтесь на досуге с соглашениями по именованию `package`-й.

Comment: Не помогло, спасибо, ознакомлюсь с правилами package-й.

Comment: Во всех четырёх циклах исправили? В случае ошибки, в консоль должен выбрасываться стектрейс исключения. Покажите его.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
 at com.ticTacToe.Game.eraseField(Game.java:11)
 at com.ticTacToe.Main.main(Main.java:6)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
 at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)

Process finished with exit code 1

Вот что выводит

Comment: Что говорит о том, что вы не сделали, как написано выше.

Comment: Сделал, изменил в циклах с "<=" на "<", и выводит, то что описано выше.

Comment: Во всех _четырёх_ циклах?

Comment: А нет, я не внимателен. Спасибо за то что откликнулись. for (int j = 0; j <= FIELD_SIZE; i++)  - здесь i надо заменить на j.